# Mauchly Sphericity test conditions

Tags: repeated-measures, sphericity

Can a sphericity test be done without doing a RM-ANOVA? My objective is to test whether the variance of the pairwise differencces are equal (by sphericity I mean this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauchly%27s_sphericity_test#What_is_sphericity.3F)

In other terms: what are the conditions that have to be met in order to do sphericity test? if there is, are they the same as RM-ANOVA?